# Syntax Error Unexpected token only for Jelly bean phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an HTML5 based android app. The app was working perfectly fine and was able to fetch data from the backend system. However, since today the app is reporting a weird error while fetching data SyntaxError Unexpected token and shows some gibberish character. This error is occurring only on phones having Jelly Bean (Android 4.2.1); it was working perfectly fine till last week and there has been no change in the code. In the below code the ajax call goes into the error section for Android 4.2.1.

```
function getData() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-SMP-APPCID', connectionID);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(appUser + ":" + appPass));
        },
        url: calURL, //calURL is the connection to backend
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error fetching Data - " + errorThrown);
            hideMainContent(false);
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Error fetching data - " + errorThrown;
            if(errorThrown.indexOf("Unauthorized") > -1){**// Invalid token reported here**
                document.getElementById("setButton").innerHTML = "<p>Unauthorized error can occur if your password has expired or changed. Below option can be used to change application password to your new Password.</p><button onclick=\"changePassword()\" class=\"ui-btn style=\"margin:10% 25%;width:50%;\">Change Password</button>";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("setButton").innerHTML = "<p>Temporary communication error. Please refresh after some time.</p>";
            }
        },
        success: function(jsonData) {

        },
    });
    return;
}
```

[image: Error Image 1]
[image: Error Image 2]

Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `if(errorThrown.toString().indexOf("Unauthorized") > -1){`

Comment: According to jQuery documentation errorThrown could be an error *object*. 

error - Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
... and an optional exception object, if one occurred...  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: errorThrown.toString() did not help. There is some invalid processing happening in jelly bean phones. I have put in additional alerts to see what request is send to backend and it is not creating any problem. Surprisingly what has changed for Jelly Bean over the last week that is making the app to crash.